# Remove countdown from Growl Notification with angular

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-notify

I am using growl.success feature to pop up some message in my website.

Does anyone know how to remove the display of countdown that is visible in the corner showing how much time is left for pop up to fade away?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Time To Live Countdown feature:

app.config(['growlProvider', function(growlProvider) {

```
   growlProvider.globalDisableCountDown(true);
```

}]);

To read more about it go to:
http://janstevens.github.io/angular-growl-2/#time-to-live-countdown